# need to create a random number between 10 and 20

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers, generator

I am trying to generate a random number between 10 and 20 for my program but the numbers being generated are less than 1 and are to 2 decimal places e.g. 0.64, 0.34 etc..

```
Dim TrigB As Random
    Dim numberb As Integer
    TrigB = New Random
    numberb = TrigB.Next(10, 20)
    TrigRdmb.Text = numberb.ToString
```

what do i need to change so that it produces a number between 10 and 20

thanks

Comment: `TrigB.Next(10, 21)` for a range of 10-20 inclusive...something else is fiddling with the result if you are getting fractions in the result.  Dont create a new random over and over - create one for the app.  As [shown here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z4AWp3#)

Comment: `Random.Next()` returns an integer,  If you are getting decimals, your code is messed up somewhere else

Comment: **Sadly** the accepted answer on that proposed dupe is one of the worst ones; new users dont look past the magical green checkmark.

Comment: thanks it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the `TrigB.Next(10, 20)` which you should have written as `TrigB.Next(10, 21)` to make it inclusive of `20`, your code is fine. For `Random.Next` will `Return` `Integer`

If you get value less than 1, then it is likely you call `Random.NextDouble` and not `Random.Next`.

Comment: thanks it is working now